Проблема с отправкой данных формы из Telegram WebApp с использованием Vue.js и FastAPI
я разрабатываю Mini-app с обратной связью на базе Telegram бота. Бекенд написан на FastAPI, фронтенд на Vue.js. Данные с формы успешно отправляются через обычный браузер, но когда я использую WebApp в Telegram, данные формы приходят пустыми.
Вот как я получаю данные в FastAPI:
@router.post("/submitform")
async def handle_form(request: Request):
    try:
        form_data = await request.json()
        form_input = FormInput(**form_data)
        print(form_input.name, form_input.email, form_input.message)
        return {"message": "Data received"}
    except Exception as e:
        print('2')
        logger.error(f"Ошибка при обработке формы: {e}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Ошибка при обработке данных")

И вот моя форма на Vue:
<template>
  <div class="ufive-feedback">
    <section id="feedback">
      <h1>Форма обратной связи</h1>
      <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
        <div class="field name-box" :class="{'focused': isNameFocused}">
          <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Как Вас зовут?" v-model="name" @focus="isNameFocused = true" @blur="isNameFocused = false" />
          <label for="name">Имя</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field email-box" :class="{'focused': isEmailFocused}">
          <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Ваш e-mail адрес" v-model="email" @focus="isEmailFocused = true" @blur="isEmailFocused = false" />
          <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field msg-box" :class="{'focused': isMsgFocused}">
          <textarea id="msg" rows="4" placeholder="Излагайте ваш вопрос четко и подробно" v-model="message" @focus="isMsgFocused = true" @blur="isMsgFocused = false" ></textarea>
          <label for="msg">Текст</label>
        </div>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

Обработка отправки формы на JavaScript выглядит так:
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: '',
      isNameFocused: false,
      isEmailFocused: false,
      isMsgFocused: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async submitForm() {
      const formData = {
        name: this.name,
        email: this.email,
        message: this.message,
      };
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://127.0.0.1:3000/submitform', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        });
        
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        alert('Спасибо за ваше сообщение!');
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

Я перепробовал все методы и даже привлек коллег к решению этой задачи, но проблема остаётся. Как мне отправить данные из формы, чтобы они корректно обрабатывались на сервере при использовании Telegram WebApp?

Алернтнул formData, она все таки не пустая. Но при отправке данных по адресу https://127.0.0.1:3000/submitform, происходит ошибка Failed to fetch

А вы на локальный сервер отправляете через https ?

Да, в вебе все работает, а через WebApp нет, может там метод какой то есть.
